Why is $|\log|\sqrt{U_1}-\sqrt{U_0}||^{1/4}$ approximately normal?
Let $U_0,U_1\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\text{Uniform}(0,1)$.
I noticed that the random variable $Z=|\log|\sqrt{U_1}-\sqrt{U_0}||^{1/4}$, after standardizing, is very close to a $N(0,1)$ distribution.
Is this a numerical coincidence, or is there an intuitive reason for this?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

N = 100_000_000
X1 = np.random.uniform(0,1,N)
X0 = np.random.uniform(0,1,N)
Z = np.abs(np.log(np.abs(np.sqrt(X1)-np.sqrt(X0))))**0.25
Z = (Z - np.mean(Z))/np.std(Z)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.hist(Z, bins=1000, density=True, alpha=0.5, label='$Z = |\log|U_1-U_0||^{1/4}$')
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1), 'k-', label='N(0,1) PDF')
plt.legend()

EDIT:
Comparison between the density 温泽海 found and a normal density:


I doubt it. The way you define $Z$ implies that $Z \ge 0$, meanwhile a normal distribution can take negative values

The line "Z = (Z - np.mean(Z))/np.std(Z)" is most likely the culprit.

Bell-shaped curves tend to look very similar if you scale them properly.  The difference is the height of the tails, which is hard to see by eye because the heights are already small.

@ThànhNguyễn I agree it won't be exactly normal for the reason you stated, but the distribution seems close over some finite interval, say $[-4,4]$. Similar to how we say a Binomial distribution is "approximately" normal, even though it's $\geq 0$ too.

@Rabbithawke only meant to center and rescale the plot there, shouldn't affect the shape.

As the comments suggest, $Z$ is never negative and thus would not be supported on $\mathbb{R}$ as the normal distribution. However, can $Z$ look similar to normal in some way on its support so that once standardized it looks awfully similar to normal distribution ? The answer is yes. What I would like to do from this point on is to treat this question as a (somewhat tiresome) exercise for the use of transformations/convolutions when calculating probability density function.
I reserve $\chi$ as the symbol for indicator functions. That is, $\chi_A(x)=1$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ otherwise. All densities are with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
First of all, here are some results whose proofs can be found basically anywhere so I will just state them :

If $X>0$ almost surely and $X$ has density $f$, then, for a fixed $\alpha > 0$, the density of $X^{\alpha}$ is :

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\alpha}x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1} f(x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}) \chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation*}

If $X>0$ almost surely and $X$ has density $f$, then the density of $\ln X$ is :

\begin{equation*}
e^x f(e^x)
\end{equation*}

If $X$ has density $f$, then the density of $\mid X \mid$ is :

\begin{equation*}
[f(x)+f(-x)]\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation*}
To start, we know that the densities of $U_0$ and $U_1$ are both $\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$. Use 1, we know that the density of $\sqrt{U_0}$ is $2x\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$. Simple manipulations show that the density of $-\sqrt{U_1}$ is $-2x\chi_{(-1,0)}(x)$. By independence, the density of $V = \sqrt{U_0} -\sqrt{U_1}$ is calculated by using the convolution as proved https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions .
That is :
\begin{equation*}
f_V(v) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 2x \chi_{(0,1)}(x)(-2)(v-x)\chi_{(-1,0)}(v-x)dx
\\ = \chi_{(0,1)}(v) (\frac{2}{3}v^3 - 2v + \frac{4}{3})
+ \chi_{(-1,0)}(v) (-\frac{2}{3}v^3 + 2v + \frac{4}{3})
\end{equation*}
Therefore, by 3, the density of $\mid \sqrt{U_0} -\sqrt{U_1} \mid$ is given by :
\begin{equation*}
\chi_{(0,1)}(x) (\frac{4}{3}x^3 - 4x + \frac{8}{3})
\end{equation*}
Then we apply 2 to know that the density of $\ln \mid \sqrt{U_0} -\sqrt{U_1} \mid$ is :
\begin{equation*}
\chi_{(-\infty,0)}(x) (\frac{4}{3}e^{4x} - 4e^{2x} + \frac{8}{3}e^x)
\end{equation*}
Apply 3 and 1, we get that the density of $Z = \mid \ln \mid \sqrt{U_0} -\sqrt{U_1} \mid \mid^{\frac{1}{4}}$ to be :
\begin{equation*}
f_Z(z) = z^3 (\frac{16}{3}e^{-4z^{4}} - 16e^{-2z^{4}} + \frac{32}{3}e^{-z^{4}}) \chi_{(0,\infty)}(z)
\end{equation*}
To see whether it is similar to normal, we plot it :

So yes, this looks very normal (although it is steeper). It is not a numerical coincidence.

It is asked why such a formula of $f_Z(z)$ gives such a close total variation distance to the density of normal with appropriately chosen mean and variance. The most direct answer is still that, from the graph, this distribution is approximately symmetric and bell shaped so that once normalized it looks very similar to a normal distribution. Why does the formula yield such a similarity ? The only thing I can say is that it is the result of solving integral (that is, algerba).
I would like to introduce a more reasonable way (and, by the way, quantify the observation for symmetry) to detect the similarity with normal distribution, through skewness and kurtosis.
Put :
\begin{equation*}
\mu = \mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_0^{\infty}z^4 (\frac{16}{3}e^{-4z^{4}} - 16e^{-2z^{4}} + \frac{32}{3}e^{-z^{4}})dz \approx 1.1063319735
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\sigma = \sqrt{\text{Var}(Z)} = \sqrt{\int_0^{\infty}(z-\mu)^2z^3 (\frac{16}{3}e^{-4z^{4}} - 16e^{-2z^{4}} + \frac{32}{3}e^{-z^{4}})dz }\approx 0.183545656183
\end{equation*}
The skewness is :
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma})^3z^3 (\frac{16}{3}e^{-4z^{4}} - 16e^{-2z^{4}} + \frac{32}{3}e^{-z^{4}})dz \approx 0.0411324798029
\end{equation*}
The skewness of normal is $0$.
The kurtosis is :
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma})^4z^3 (\frac{16}{3}e^{-4z^{4}} - 16e^{-2z^{4}} + \frac{32}{3}e^{-z^{4}})dz \approx 2.95832840404
\end{equation*}
The kurtosis of normal is $3$.
We can say that, by looking at skewness and kurtosis, the difference between this distribution and normal distribution is rather minimal. Since the skewness is slightly positive, the distribution is not symmetric and has (slightly) more mass on the left side of mean. Since there is less kurtosis, the normal distribution is slightly more dispersed at tails.

Thanks! This looks correct. Is it obvious that this expression (involving x^3 and a combination of different $e^{-cx^4}$ terms can be well-approximated by a Gaussian density? It's not immediately obviously to me that this should be the case. Added a plot in the original post for comparison.

What kind of approximation are you looking for ? As pointed out by other comments, once we confirm that this distribution looks symmetric bell shaped (it might very well not), it is pretty similar to Gaussian once standardized.

Apologies for being vague... my impression at least is that more than just being symmetric and vaguely bell-shaped, $f_Z$ is quite close to a normal density, e.g. in a total variation distance sense $d_{TV}(p,q) = \frac{1}{2}\int|p(x)-q(x)|dx$. I'm getting that the TV distance from $f_Z$ to this particular normal density is 0.006, while the closest "bell-shaped" density of e.g. the type $\propto 1/(1+c(x-\mu)^2)$ is 0.13.
Perhaps just as a numerical question at this point: Is there a reason to expect  $f_Z(z)\approx \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(z-\mu)^2)$ for some $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Happy to attribute it to numerical coincidence and award the bounty, but thought I'd ask in case you/someone else had an idea. It seems a little surprising this random combination of $x^3$ and $\exp(-cx^4)$ would be that numerically close in L1 distance.

I have edited the response.

@DDD The period is over. If you like my answer, please accept and award the bounty.
